# Render/Redirect to Another View Using Portlets

Tags: php, yii, portlet

I have a login portlet up and running that's based on [this](http://yii.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.0/docs/blog/portlet.login.txt) tutorial.  It works just fine, however, if there is an error with the login form the error messages are displayed within the portlet and they aren't very prominent.

The portlet follows:

```
class UserLogin extends Portlet
{
    public $title='Login';

    protected function renderContent()
    {
        $form=new LoginForm;
        if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {
            $form->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
            if($form->validate())
                $this->controller->refresh();
        }
        $this->render('userLogin',array('form'=>$form));
    }
}
```

I would prefer any error to cause the login attempt to redirect to a full login form where the errors can be displayed prominently and it will be clear to the user something has gone wrong.

Something along the lines of:

```
if($form->validate())
    $this->controller->refresh();
else                
    $this->render('login',array('form'=>$form));
```

The else bit isn't correct, however, and I can't seem to figure out how to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use something like

```
else
{
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('login', 'Login error');
    $this->controller->redirect(array('account/login'));
}
```

where `account/login` is the controller/action pair for separate login page. `CWebUser`'s flash messages system is used to deliver error message into new action (See Yii cookbook [How to work with flash messages](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/cookbook/21/)).

Comment: Works beautifully.  I simply passed the entire form with Yii::app()->user->setFlash('login', $form);.